# Bunch of if conditions - simplified?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, switch-statement

How can I a bunch of my if conditions simpler?

For example:

```
statments:

condition 1: $row['age'] > 5;
condition 2: $row['id'] > 10;
condition 3: $row['number'] == '100';
condition 4: $row['gender'] == 'male';
condition 5: $row['state'] == 'New York';
```

**How can i do something like this: if two of the conditions above exists, echo "welcome"?** I was thinking about using an array? Maybe something else would be better?

```
if(two of the conditions above are true) {
    echo "Welcome";
}
```

Comment: How far have you got so far, show us the code

Comment: You could just use a counter, and increment it with every passed condition.

Comment: Why is MySQL tag included in this question?

Comment: @Uueerdo that is a good idea, how can I put the if conditions? Can put it in an array and do `if exists in array`... ?

Comment: @JasonBale see the answer I posted; I think building an array of conditions (if that is what you were suggesting) would just be over-complicating things; even if it can be done, all it would do for this particular task is reduce readability to save (at most) one line per condition.

Answer (score 2):

```
    if (isnull($row['age'] > 5,0) + isnull($row['id'] > 10,0) + 
        isnull($row['number'] == '100',0) + isnull($row['gender'] == 
        'male',0) + isnull($row['state'] == 'New York',0) >= 2) {
        echo "Welcome";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My php-syntax is rusty, so so this explanation of what my comment was suggesting should be considered borderline pseudo-code:

```
int conditionsMet = 0;
if ($row['age'] > 5)
   conditionsMet++;
if ($row['id'] > 10)
   conditionsMet++;
if ($row['number'] == '100')
   conditionsMet++;
if ($row['gender'] == 'male')
   conditionsMet++;
if ($row['state'] == 'New York')
   conditionsMet++;

if(conditionsMet >= 2) {
    echo "Welcome";
}
```